# Hosting personal pages over a Redmine installation

Tags: apache, apache2, redmine, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I currently installed redmine on my server, and configured apache2 to run it in a virtualhost over mydomain.com

Thing is I also want to host some extra pages, at mydomain.com/personal, but since redmine is running the page is never found. How can I override this configuration to run both redmine and some personal pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) directive to just create a virtual directory, which maps /public with some other real directory on the filesystem.

Comment: If I map an alias to the public directory I'll just see the public folder contents instead of redmine starting page. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I managed to get it working, I was missing RailsBaseURI. Thanks!